# The (Eclipse Android App) project is missing required library, after importing from a different device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, export

I have exported a project from a laptop, as an archive file. i did this through `File>Export>General>Archive` File. Then `Import>General>Archive` file. It comes up with an error saying:

```
 "ResourceProject 'PartyOrganiser' is missing required library:
 'C:\Documents and Settings\jstedman\My
 Documents\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar'  PartyOrganiser      Build
 path   Build Path Problem"
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue. It also says: Unable to resolve target "android 19"

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the other laptop try to have **android 19** version

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar problem. If you already have android-19 lib but still the error persists. 
Try compiling the project with some other android version like 4.4 or GDK or anything and then again compiling with your required version. After that, if the problem persists, then try to go to properties, and then libraries, and then try deleting the libraries which are causing the problem.
 I hope it helps.